# (android firebase) determine reaching last item when paginating

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let say I have 100 items (actually it's much more than 100 in reality) stored in Firebase Realtime Database. So I decided to use pagination, I use the Query#addValueEventListener() function for query and only load 20 items each request, the last queried item's key passed to the Query#startAt() to get the next 20 items. It worked well so far

But the problem is after I reach the last item (the 100th item) in Firebase Database, it will give me back all items (100 items) hold in Database for the next request.
Currently, I have to check the key id passed to Query#startAt() and the last queried item's key id are equal or not, if true then I was reach the end. Honestly I think this is not a nicely solution

So anyone here has better solutions for this case, please help me.
thanks in advance!

the code here

```
private var lastKey: String? = null
fun requestItems(startAtId: String?){
    val query = dbRef.orderByKey()
    if(!startAtId.isNullOrBlank()){*the problem here*
        query.startAt(startAtId)
    }
    query.limitToFirst(10)
    query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val lastKey = it.children.last().key
            if (lastKey.equals(startAtId)){
                //has reached the last item
                //ignore the result
            }else{
                //do something with the result
                lastKey = latestKey
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(dataSnapshot: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })

}
```

**update**
I just realized the problem I was faced is at initializing the Query object (1st line to 5th line) in the requestItems() function. It always returns whole items from db. I changed that initializing block to the bellow block. I don't know any different from them but it worked as pagination.

```
val query = if(startAtId.isNullOrBlank()){
        dbRef.orderByKey()
    }else{
        dbRef.orderByKey()
                .startAt(startAtId)

    }.limitToFirst(10)
```

But there is still no sign to point out that it reach the last item in db. after reaching the end Firebase always returns the last item, I think that happened because of startAt(startAtId) function and there is no such a function like startAtAfter(startAtId)

I attach the [json file here](https://gist.github.com/linhphan0108/d88cc2247d46a9a722e1ec626b5e7fc9) that is not real data in db, but they has same structure.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem if you reduce code to a single query, where you pass in a hardcoded value into `startAt`? If so, please update your question to only show that code. And then please edit it to also include the minimal JSON needed to reproduce it (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your answer. I updated my problem

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase `Query` object is immutable. Whenever you call one of the `orderBy`, `startAt` and other methods, it returns a new `Query` object. So you will need to capture that object in a variable:

```
val query = dbRef.orderByKey()
if(!startAtId.isNullOrBlank()){
    query = query.startAt(startAtId)
}
query = query.limitToFirst(10)
...
```

That's also why your updated construct works: you've put all query-building into a single chain and capture the results. But while it works, I personally find the result less readable than the one above.

Comment: thanks Frank that is an interesting information. but do you know how to determine reaching end in db?

Comment: If you get fewer results than you requested, you know there are no more results.